# Google Cloud Deployment Updating module [default]...failed

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

While deploying my Ruby on Rails App on Google Cloud, I am facing error :

```
"error": {
        "message": "Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: 20151118t112244.388647928663960363", 
        "code": 13
    }
```

Complete log is as follows :

```
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Batch request done; responses [<Operation
 endTime: u'2015-11-17T21:59:27.755-08:00'
 id: 12441364253937073796L
 insertTime: u'2015-11-17T21:58:56.625-08:00'
 kind: u'compute#operation'
 name: u'operation-1447826336437-524ca567ad308-57fe340b-1c8f58e7'
 operationType: u'delete'
 progress: 100
 selfLink: u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/listup-admin-dashboard/zones/us-central1-f/operations/operation-1447826336437-524ca567ad308-57fe340b-1c8f58e7'
 startTime: u'2015-11-17T21:58:56.911-08:00'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 0)
 targetId: 12256056891934276088L
 targetLink: u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/listup-admin-dashboard/zones/us-central1-f/instances/gae-builder-vm-20151118t112244'
 user: u'saurabhjain1592@gmail.com'
 warnings: []
 zone: u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/listup-admin-dashboard/zones/us-central1-f'>]
DEBUG: Sleeping for 9s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operations to inspect: [<Operation
 endTime: u'2015-11-17T21:59:27.755-08:00'
 id: 12441364253937073796L
 insertTime: u'2015-11-17T21:58:56.625-08:00'
 kind: u'compute#operation'
 name: u'operation-1447826336437-524ca567ad308-57fe340b-1c8f58e7'
 operationType: u'delete'
 progress: 100
 selfLink: u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/listup-admin-dashboard/zones/us-central1-f/operations/operation-1447826336437-524ca567ad308-57fe340b-1c8f58e7'
 startTime: u'2015-11-17T21:58:56.911-08:00'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 0)
 targetId: 12256056891934276088L
 targetLink: u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/listup-admin-dashboard/zones/us-central1-f/instances/gae-builder-vm-20151118t112244'
 user: u'saurabhjain1592@gmail.com'
 warnings: []
 zone: u'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/listup-admin-dashboard/zones/us-central1-f'>]
Deleted [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/listup-admin-dashboard/zones/us-central1-f/instances/gae-builder-vm-20151118t112244].
INFO: Explict Display.
DEBUG: Updates are available.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...\DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating module [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "target": "apps/listup-admin-dashboard/modules/default/versions/20151118t112244", 
        "insertTime": "2015-11-18T05:59:16.526Z", 
        "method": "google.appengine.v1beta4.Versions.CreateVersion", 
        "user": "saurabhjain1592@gmail.com", 
        "operationType": "create_version", 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1beta4.OperationMetadata"
    }, 
    "done": true, 
    "name": "apps/listup-admin-dashboard/operations/dd144925-834f-412f-aac6-179dbe297388", 
    "error": {
        "message": "Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: 20151118t112244.388647928663960363", 
        "code": 13
    }
}
Updating module [default]...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: 20151118t112244.388647928663960363
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/saurabhjain/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 605, in Execute
    result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/saurabhjain/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1228, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/saurabhjain/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/surface/preview/app/deploy.py", line 296, in Run
    images.get(module))
  File "/Users/saurabhjain/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 76, in DeployModule
    return operations.WaitForOperation(self.client.apps_operations, operation)
  File "/Users/saurabhjain/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/api/operations.py", line 54, in WaitForOperation
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(completed_operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [13] Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: 20151118t112244.388647928663960363
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Version: 20151118t112244.388647928663960363
```

Answer (score 1):

This often means that your code had an error that prevented the instance from starting up successfully.  You can probably find the actual error in the cloud logging console.